# PHP Issues with GetElementById, getAttribute, and StrPos

Tags: php

I'm a relative beginner to PHP and I'm having an issue with a web scraper script that I'm trying to develop.  The script is designed to grab a VBulletin forum page, then parse through the hyperlinks on the page to find the ones that include a particular "id" element (i.e. only the links that point to message threads posted on the forum).  Each of the desired links includes an "id" element that begins "thread_title_[Thread # here]."  I came up with the idea of using STRPOS as a filter to examine each "id" element from the collected links and check if they contain the fragment "thread_title".  Unfortunately, my efforts don't seem to be bearing fruit.

I will paste the code excerpt below... at the risk of being labeled a complete noobie. ;)  Hopefully I'm not doing something terribly stupid.  Thanks for the help

```
   $d = new domdocument();

   $d->loadHTMLfile("forum3.html");

    $links = $d->getElementsByTagName('a');
    echo '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" encoding="utf-8" lang="ar-sa">';

    foreach ($links as $link)
    {
        $threadTitleExists = $link->getAttribute('id');
        $pos = strpos($threadTitleExists, 'thread_title');  
        $threadTitle = $link->nodeValue;
        if ($link->hasAttribute('id') && ($pos==0))
        {    
             $threadTitle = trim(preg_replace('#/\s*\([^)]*\)/', ' ', $threadTitle));
             echo "Thread number: " . $threadTitleExists . "<br>Thread title: " . $threadTitle . "<p>";
        }

         else 
         {

             continue;

         }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the line

```
if ($link->hasAttribute('id') && $pos != false)
```

to

```
if ($link->hasAttribute('id') && $pos !== false)
```

[strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) returns 0 if the haystack begins with the needle, which evaluates as false when using the loosely typed comparison operator. There's a warning on the manual page (linked) to use the `===` operator instead.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot... but I'm still not getting the hyperlink anchor text via nodeValue.  It keeps showing up blank.  Any ideas?

Comment: what does `var_dump($link->nodeValue)` yield? If it isn't empty, I'd look at the regex you're applying to `$threadTitle`

Comment: Yeah... it definitely isn't empty... I'm seeing bits and pieces of the anchor text.  Thanks again -- I'm going to take another look and see if I can sort out the problem.

Comment: I fixed it... can't believe an echo/print_r substitution was all that was needed.  ARGH!!! ;)